# why video autoplay is not working when use that with bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Video is not auto-play.
same code is working if place in a different file but the same code is not working with my page.?
can anyone help with this.

Now working URL: https://pcbmagic.com/

in the above URL video is not autoplay.
i have tried everything that's possible but still not working.
maybe my explanation is not good but hope you can understand and if any clarification needed you can comment.

**thanks in advance.**

```css
.video
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 512px;
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        #carousel .carousel-item {
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100%;
          min-height: 350px;
          background: no-repeat center center scroll;
          background-size: cover;
        }
        
        #carousel .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
          transition: -webkit-transform 2s ease;
          transition: transform 2s ease;
          transition: transform 2s ease, -webkit-transform 2s ease;
        }
        
        #carousel .carousel-item .caption {
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
          padding: 40px;
          color: white;
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
        }
        
        #carousel .caption h2 {
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-delay: 2s;
        }
        
        #carousel .caption p {
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-delay: 2.2s;
        }
        
        #carousel .caption a {
          animation-duration: 1s;
          animation-delay: 2.4s;
        }
        
        /* Button */
        .delicious-btn {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #ffffff;
            border: none;
            border-left: 3px solid #1c8314;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 0 30px;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 35px;
            font-weight: 600;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
            transition-duration: 500ms;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            background-color: #40ba37;
            margin-top: 15px;
        }
        
        .delicious-btn.active, .delicious-btn:hover, .delicious-btn:focus {
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 600;
          color: #ffffff;
          background-color: #1c8314;
          border-color: #40ba37;
        }
        
        .slider-content-main
        {
            background: white;
            padding: 25px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide hero-slides" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" style="border: 1px solid #dedede;">
              <video autoplay loop class="video" id="vid">
                     <source src="https://pcbmagic.com/small5.mp4" width="1024" type="video/mp4" >
                     Your browser does not support the video tag.
              </video>
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <div class="container d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="row align-items-center ml-4" style="height: 512px;">
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 slider-content-main">
                    <div class="caption animated fadeIn">
                      <h2 class="animated fadeInLeft">Boat Excursions</h2>
                      <p class="animated fadeInRight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tristique nisl vitae luctus sollicitudin. Fusce consectetur sem eget dui tristique, ac posuere arcu varius.</p>
                      <a class="animated fadeInUp btn delicious-btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="carousel-item ">
              <div class="container d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="row align-items-center ml-4" style="height: 512px;">
                  <div class="col-12 col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 slider-content-main">
                    <div class="caption animated fadeIn">
                      <h2 class="animated fadeInLeft">Explore the river valley</h2>
                      <p class="animated fadeInRight">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
                      <a class="animated fadeInUp btn delicious-btn" href="#">Learn more</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--<div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://pcbwayfile.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/banner/21/03/25/1808173691783t.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              
            </div>-->
          </div>
        </div>
        
     </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add muted in your video tag :-).

```
<video autoplay loop ➡️ muted ⬅️ class="video">
```

it's because google don't allow video autoplay having audio. you can read crome policy by below link.

only allow once user interact with that video like. click,tap etc.

https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/